# Offered TA position two months before, head assitant no longer responds

Tags: teaching, teaching-assistant

At the beginning of the last semester, I responded to a TA offer which was online, met with the head assistant of the course, meeting was positive, and I did all the needed talks and paperworks with the administration and gave all the information needed and signed up for a contract. This week our semester started (where I should be assisting), and head assistant never ever called me nor sent me an e-mail, even though I contacted him by email twice in the last two weeks. I do not know what is going on, and I feel I should catch up and follow the course material, but I do not want to waste my time if I am not going to be a TA at all. This situation is really weird, especially since it is happening on Top 50 ARWU university, and I do not understand what is going on.

Moreover, is it possible that he rejected me because I didn't get a good enough grade on the course he was also a head assistant at last semester and has small relations to one I should be assisting at, even though I was never asked for a grade transcript? Did this ever happen?

Comment: The ranking of a university has no correlation with the communication skills of its teaching assistants.

Comment: @astronat I did my undergraduates in the above top 1000 in a third world country, and this kind of behaviour I have only seen there, and that was due to organizational skills, which here at grad where I am right now has never happened to me until now.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend contacting whoever is responsible for scheduling TA assignments in your department overall -- perhaps the assistant chair or the graduate director. Say that you believe you signed up for a TA assignment, but haven't been assigned any duties yet -- and ask him or her how to proceed.

The most likely explanation, in my opinion, is that the head assistant is merely being disorganized -- a common phenomenon in academia! But it's impossible to say.